# Multiple injecting error or nullpointerException

Tags: java, netbeans, glassfish

I have created sample database in derby in netbeans.

I generated persistence.xml

I generated entity classes from Database.

I created

**courseDAO**

```
@Stateless
public class courseDAO {
    @PersistenceContext
    EntityManager em;

    public courseDAO(){}
    public List<Course> getCourses(){
        return em.createNativeQuery("Select * From Course", Course.class).getResultList();
    }
}
```

**factory class**

```
@Stateless
public class courseFactory {

   @Inject
   courseDAO course;

    public courseFactory() {
    }

    public List<Course> getCourses(){
        return course.getCourses();
    }
}
```

and route that should take care of it

```
@Path("course")
public class courseRoute {

    @Inject
    courseFactory courseFactory;
    @GET
    public String hi(){

        List<Course> l = courseFactory.getCourses();
        GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
        Gson gson = builder.create();
        return gson.toJson(l);
    }
}
```

yet when i run project and create get request on route it throws

> javax.servlet.ServletException: A MultiException has 1 exceptions. 
>   They are:
>   1. org.glassfish.hk2.api.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: There was no object available for injection at
>   SystemInjecteeImpl(requiredType=courseFactory,parent=courseRoute,qualifiers={},position=-1,optional=false,self=false,unqualified=null,6181406)
>   root cause
>
> A MultiException has 1 exceptions.  They are:
>   1. org.glassfish.hk2.api.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: There was no object available for injection at
>   SystemInjecteeImpl(requiredType=courseFactory,parent=courseRoute,qualifiers={},position=-1,optional=false,self=false,unqualified=null,6181406)
>   root cause
>
> org.glassfish.hk2.api.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: There was no
>   object available for injection at
>   SystemInjecteeImpl(requiredType=courseFactory,parent=courseRoute,qualifiers={},position=-1,optional=false,self=false,unqualified=null,6181406)

However when i remove stateless from `courseFactory` and create its instance in courseRoute e.g

```
courseFactory c = new courseFactory()
List<Course> l = c.getCourses();
```

It throws nullpointerException.

I keep trying to fix this but everytime i create another bug, What is the right way how to fix it?

Comment: thats typo, thanks for pointing out

Comment: It's ok, no problema.